# Como agrupar por dia do mês no MySQL

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, select, data

Gostaria de saber como faço um select onde eu possa exibir em colunas os registros de entrada e saída dos funcionários na portaria.
A tabela é assim:

```
╔════╦══════╦═════════════════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ ID ║ Nome ║ DHEntrada           ║ DHSaída             ║
╠════╬══════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 1  ║ João ║ 2017-02-06 11:05:22 ║ 2017-02-06 14:05:22 ║
║ 2  ║ José ║ 2017-02-06 08:05:22 ║ 2017-02-06 10:05:22 ║
║ 3  ║ João ║ 2017-02-06 08:05:22 ║ 2017-02-06 09:05:22 ║
║ 2  ║ José ║ 2017-02-05 12:05:22 ║ 2017-02-05 18:05:22 ║
║ 2  ║ José ║ 2017-02-05 08:44:22 ║ 2017-02-05 10:01:22 ║
╚════╩══════╩═════════════════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

A consulta ficaria:

```
╔═════╦════════════╦═══════════╦════════════╦═══════════╗
║Nome ║ Entr 05/02 ║ Saí 05/02 ║ Entr 06/02 ║ Saí 06/02 ║
╠═════╬════════════╬═══════════╬════════════╬═══════════╣
║João ║     0      ║     0     ║     2      ║   2       ║
║José ║     2      ║     2     ║     1      ║   1       ║
╚═════╩════════════╩═══════════╩════════════╩═══════════╝
```

Comment: Você terá as datas definidas ou pretende que seja tudo criado dinamicamente? E o que significa o 0, 1 e 2 na segunda tabela?

Comment: Uau!!! Ao tempo que não via estas tabelas ASCII!!!

Comment: @Sorack As datas são dinâmicas sim. Os números 0,1 e 2 são a incidência de entrada e as incidências de saída de cada elemento (no caso "João" e "José") nas datas especificadas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente o que precisa é de um pivot table em MYSQL.

normalmente isso exige alguma complexidade na query como por exemplo saber todas as colunas que a query irá retornar.
no link abaixo voce pode conhecer um pouco mais sobre pivot table em MYSQL

http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=78

Embora nao seja exatamente o pivot pois Mysql não possui a funcao de pivot (a nao ser que seja uma nova funcionalidade) entao neste caso voce tera de fazer varias funcoes de agregacoes.

exemplo:

```
select nome
       ,count(case when day(dataEntrada) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as [dia 1 do mes]
       ,count(case when day(dataEntrada) = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as [dia 2 do mes]
       ....
       ,count(case when day(dataEntrada) = 31 then 1 else 0 end) as [dia 31 do mes]


from tabelaPonto
where month(dataEntrada) = 1
group by nome;
```

existe formas de melhorar esta query mas eu iria por esse caminho.

Comment: Ôpa!!! Valeu demais! Vou fazer o teste aqui. Obrigado.

Comment: disponha! se possível após o teste poste se a solução proposta lhe foi útil

Comment: Deu muito certo! Obrigado, cara! Me tirou de um sufoco de semanas quebrando a cabeça!

Comment: @SnowBG A resposta lhe foi útil? Em caso positivo, não esqueça de marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Comment: @Sorack! Feito. Obrigado.